Force venv to create virtual environment in "bin" instead of "Scripts" folder
According to the Blender docs you can replace the python installation that comes with blender with your own:

Copy or link the extensions into Blender’s Python subdirectory so Blender can access them, you can also copy the entire Python installation into Blender’s subdirectory, replacing the one Blender comes with. This works as long as the Python versions match and the paths are created in the same relative locations. Doing this has the advantage that you can redistribute this bundle to others with Blender including any extensions you rely on.

I want to use my own virtual environment for Blender, however the problem is, on Windows the python.exe for virtual environments will be placed in
<path/to/venv>/Scripts/python.exe
while Blenders python installation is paced in
<path/to/blender>/python/bin/python.exe
After testing around, simply renaming folders or moving files will mess up activation scripts and links for packages it seems. Question therefore is, if it might be possible to change the paths of the Windows installation for virtual environments?

You can link your bin as said Scripts:
mklink /d "C:\path\to\blender\python\bin" "C:\path\to\venv\Scripts"

Naturally you first need to rename or remove (not really recommended) original Scripts folder

Looks good, only problem remaining is that locally installed pip modules don't seem to get recognized (meaning if I install my python project via pip install -e . it will get installed and show up on pip list, but I get a ModuleNotFoundError when importing it.) I guess however, this is a case for a separate post.

One last note - the last sentence in the answer does not really make sense in my case. I need to delete the original bin folder, not the Scripts folder - which is ok since I want to replace original blender python anyway

I meant you need to make your target name non-existing before linking otherwise it will fail
